# how to activate numpy random.binomial function on matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have matrix df (size 4*4).
I want to simulate new values from the binomial distribution based on the values on each ij value of the matrix.

(if the value on specific component in the matrix is 10 i want to trade it with **np.random.binomial(10,0.5,1))**

is there a smart way to activate this function on the entire matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you want, but you can use [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) on a function. Here is a quick example:

```py
import numpy as np

def f(val):
    if val == 10:
        return np.random.binomial(val, 0.5, 1)
    else:
        return val

vfunc = np.vectorize(f)

a = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
out = vfunc(a)
print(out)
'''
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9  8 11] <-- may vary
 [12 13 14 15]]
'''
```